# Conditionally Activated Alert In Pine-Script Tradingview Strategy

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to use an "ON/OFF" boolean input like

```
AlertsOnOff = input (title="Alerts ON/OFF", type=input.bool, defval=false)
```

To conditionally have alert like

```
alert("This is an Alert Message", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

activated or de-activated(default) in a Tradingview strategy

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See [here](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/our-new-alerts-allow-for-dynamic-messages-22588/) in their blog post about alerts with dynamic messages.

It details that it is appropriate to use different alerts within `if` blocks. So you could easily do

```
AlertsOnOff = input (title="Alerts ON/OFF", type=input.bool, defval=false)

if AlertsOnOff
    alert("This is an Alert Message", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```